# Should I wrap all params of a method to a wrapper class?

Tags: java

For example if I have method A, which receives 4 parameters

`methodA(String,String,Object,Object)`

I think it will look cleaner if I use an object to wrap them.

```
 methodA(ParamObject)
```

But I don't know if it have any disadvantage to the performance?

Comment: Focus on correctness, readability and maintainability before performance: if you pass *these four* parameters around to a lot of places, it is much easier to know that you are passing them around correctly if you pass around a wrapper object, since you know that you're not accidentally reversing the order of the strings/objects; it's also a lot easier to add a new parameter in all of these call sites because you just update the wrapper. I doubt you'd notice a performance difference, but you'd actually have to test it for your specific application.

Comment: Long Parameter List is a [code smell](http://blog.codinghorror.com/code-smells/), but I think 4 is a reasonable number of parameters unless they belong together in some object anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Performance is the last thing you should worry about when choosing the signature of your API methods. A much more important concern is readability and maintainability of your API, which could be severely influenced by your decision to group parameters together.

First thing to consider is whether grouping some or all of the parameters makes logical sense. For example, if you have an API that looks like this

```
public void doSomething(String first, String last, Date dob) {
    ...
}
```

where the three parameters represent a person's first name, last name, and the day of birth, then changing the API to

```
public void doSomething(Person p) {
    ...
}
```

makes perfect sense.

If, on the other hand, the individual parameters are unrelated to each other, except by virtue of being parameters to the same method, then making a class to enclose them makes sense only if you plan to do something else with the invocation parameters, such as storing them for later use, forwarding them to some other method as a single unit, et cetera.

Otherwise, you should keep individual parameters instead of making a parameter-specific class.